# How to obtain max column heigh on nested row/column layout

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm creating a website with Flutter web.

But I'm facing a problem:

I would like to have a widget to take the full height available, but I can't manage to do it. I tried Flexible & Expended widget as well as Column/Row mainAxisSize with no result.

Here's my code with a preview of on of my webpages: https://codepen.io/blkkkbvsik/pen/qBqJPYr

I would like the widget `FooBar` with the progress bar to take as much height as `Title1` widget + the `Blocks` widgets from my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **IntrinsicHeight** widget

```
IntrinsicHeight(
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                color: Colors.blue,
                height: 300,
                width: 100,
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                width: 100,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
```

[image]